# Add-on support after update

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

In a previous project I wrote a Firefox extensions - nothing too complex - that used xmpp4moz, an add-on for Firefox that integrates the xmpp/Jabber protocol. At that time Firefox 3.6 most the most recent one and everything worked quite well. Now with Firefox 5 xmpp4moz does produces errors, starting with

```
Error: Component.classes['@something/something/...'] is undefined
```

and naturally resulting in further 'undefined' errors. In some sense this is ok, since xmpp4moz is officially not available for Firefox 5. And given that the last update was in 2009 I don't really expect a updated version. Currently I see the following two options:

1. Looking for alternatives/workarounds/...; so far I haven't found anything. Any ideas?
2. Trying to update/modify xmpp4moz myself to make it running in Firefox 5
   The thing is that at the moment I cannot really assess the required efforts.

Summing up, I'm stuck :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sameplace download at http://www.sameplace.cc/ appears to include a slightly newer version of xmpp4moz (I didn't really check whether `install.rdf` is the only difference from the source code repository however). Still, it is only compatible with Firefox 3.6. From the look of it, there are no big issues, main problem is that the XPCOM components aren't being registered. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM/XPCOM_changes_in_Gecko_2.0 for information on the relevant changes, usually updating the components and `chrome.manifest` is easy.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Yes I found that page and tried to modify the add-on accordingly. At first it seem promising, I fixed occuring errors step by step. But in the end I've encountered one that seem to suggest to recompile the interfaces, i.e. from the IDL to the XPT files (It looked like that all interfaces have been registered, but I got the error that a API function is unknown.). I'm no expert, so maybe this wouldn't be needed. However, in the long run, this seemed not goog idea to follow. So I kicked the add-on and switch to a xmpp Javascript library, and it seems to work.